# Custom color for Byobu status logo

Tags: byobu

The Byobu logo is based on the distribution, right? White-on-orange for Ubuntu, red-on-gray @ for Debian, etc.

[image]

However if I try to set `$LOGO` in `$HOME/.byobu/screenrc`, it will use the same white-on-gray as the tab bar. Escape codes don't work.

[image: Escape codes being ignored.]

How can I set a custom logo with custom colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Byobu actually includes a "helper function" called "`color`".  You can use this in your $HOME/.byobu/statusrc, and it will get resolved.

Example:

```
LOGO=" $(color g w)Foo$(color -) "
```

This will print a logo of " Foo ", which is white text on a green background.  The first argument to the `color` function is the background, the second is the foreground text.

You can use 8 colors, or 256 colors.  To use [256 colors](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/), do the following:

```
LOGO="$(color colour200 colour255)foo$(color -)"
```

And you can see a bunch of examples in [/usr/lib/byobu/logo](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/lib/byobu/logo).

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).*

Comment: Thanks for this great software!! I did notice that helper function, but I couldn't make sense of the letters. Where can I find a full list for the 8 colors?

Comment: You can see a bunch of examples in /usr/lib/byobu/logo

Comment: @DustinKirkland what about the other items? I had to change the hardcoded color values in `/usr/lib/byobu/network` to get the desired behaviour. Is there any way to do that without touching the lib files?